# Partition count in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

What does the number of partitions(estimate) in the tablestats query indicate?
When we query tablestats at the different nodes of a multi-node cassandra,we see different value for stable count and number of partitions at each node.Does this indicate the number of rows/partition key at a particular node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's indicate a number of partitions of specific table on given node.  Different number of partitions could be because of the data distribution in your table, number of vnodes owned by this node, etc.

Comment: In this context,is partition equivalent to token/row

Comment: token is related to specific partition. but partition may have many rows if you have clustering columns defined...